# Activity Functionality Missing

Tags: configuration, activity-settings

Following is the screenshot of my client's opportunity object. I find that activity button does not contain Log a Call and Add Task.

Going forward, Log a Call and Add Task are important functions and we need this to be implemented, along with standard pick list for Subject field.

**Investigation Done**

1) I have examined Activity Standard Object for Log-a-call and Add Task standard fields and also looked into Page layout - did not find any solution for adding log a call and add task

2) I have examined activity (related list) under opportunity and i did not find any solution of add them

3) I have examined global Actions "Log-a-Call" but did not find a way as to how to configure it for Opportunity layout

Any help is appreciated

[image: Opportunity Screen]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the Log a Call and Add Task actions to the section "Lightning and Mobile Quick Actions" on the **Opportunity** page layout. Then they'll show up in the Activity publisher. Note that this section is distinct from the Classic Quick Actions list.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance, your solution is right but i have different challenge to confront as publisher layout has predefined global actions and even after overriding them still the actions do not appear on publisher layout.

Comment: Please feel free to open a new question if you have a separate issue. I'm not sure I completely follow.